# UITableView in UICollectionView misbehaving

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

I have put UITableView in UICollectionView, and it has 4 items, but when I  scroll UICollectionView to the last item, it shows the content of the first UITableView ( So when I press option 3 button it scrolls to the last item of collectionView but the content is wrong ) . You can have a look at the below picture.
Below is the link to my project, please help me out with this issue.

[image: You can have a look at this picture]

[Link to my project](https://github.com/anirudha-music/TableViewInCollectionView/tree/master/TableView)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to reload the `UITableView` in `cellForItemAt` as mentioned below.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TableCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! TableCollectionCell
    cell.tableView.tag = indexPath.item
    cell.tableView.reloadData()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sir! I have to reload the tableView data also. Okay!